# KDB+/Q: Canonical method to represent a variable number of arguments?

Tags: mocking, kdb

I am trying to create a mock function in kdb+/q that effectively replaces a given function with one that records invocations etc. i.e.

```
wrap:{[otherFn;params]
  // update called etc.
  :otherFn[params]
}

// function that replaces target fn
someOtherFn :{show x};

// store reference etc.
// use set to replace function
`.extern.someFn set wrap[someOtherFn];
```

In this case .extern.someFn should be replaced with someOtherFn, and should be callable as such:

```
q) .extern.someFn[1];
      1
```

This is great, however when one tries to increase the number of function arguments .i.e.

```
q) .extern.someFn[1;3]; // 
      'rank
```

Signals a rank error.
Could someone please advise me how I could achieve something to this effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few (arguably valid*) reasons for doing something like this. One day I will write a printf replacement in q

The simplest way involves combining two tricks with composition and enlist.

First enlist is varadic:

```
enlist[1;2]
1 2
```

Composition can then be used to bolt together functions. I think the closest to what you want is:

```
makeWrapFunc:{[f] (
callerfunc:{[f;params] f . params}f;
'[callerfunc;enlist]
}
```

Now, whatever rank the wrapped function is, enlist will bundle up those parameters into a list for you ahead of the apply.

I used this trick in the code below for pretty much the same purpose. In my case I wanted to run some input through an existing function and a replacement function and record the outputs for later comparison.
https://github.com/darrenarmstrong85/scientist/blob/master/lib/init.q#L97

There are some ways to extend this for partial application, by inspecting the number of parameters of the wrapped function and binding using nulls, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :-)

* Arguably this is also a debugging nightmare. Caveat developor.

Comment: Entertainingly enlist is varadic to an arbitrary number of arguments, which is one really terrible way to give your function 9 parameters :-)

Comment: I would tend to agree though i'm really just using it in a test utility, so it's fine for now, anything better?

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a rank error because .extern.someFn as defined above is a function of a single variable. If you want to apply .extern.someFn to multiple inputs, you could use an iterator:

```
q).extern.someFn each 1 3;
```

Edit: You might be interested in something like this:

```
q)functionWrapper:{[f;args] f . args};
q)testFunction:{x*y};
q)wrappedFunction:functionWrapper[testFunction];
q)wrappedFunction[2 3]
6
```

Note: args needs to be a list. Multiple arguments are not separated by semi-colons. In the general case of mixed lists, specify args in the form `args:(arg1;arg2;...)`

Comment: Hey Plasma, thanks for the answer.  As noted by .extern.someFn[1;3]; , sometimes the target function does not necessarily take a list as arguments. And as such  wrappedFunction[2 3] would need to allow for wrappedFunction[2;3]. Thanks

Comment: Again this is to support mocking functionality in a test suite, and as such a simple list declaration would not work. Thanks again